# Herkunft des bairischen Verbs "rean" (Standarddeutsch: weinen)

Tags: etymology, dialect

Die 80er-Jahre Austropop-Gruppe STS ist ja auch in Deutschland bekannt, zumindest mit ihrem größten Erfolg "Fürstenfeld". Heute ging mir wieder der Text eines anderen Liedes dieser Band durch den Sinn, nämlich "Kalt und kälter".

Der Text ist, wie fast alle Texte von STS, in meiner eigentlichen Muttersprache verfasst, nämlich im oststeirischen Dialekt. Der Refrain des Liedes lautet wie folgt (zuerst steirisch, dann nochmal Standarddeutsch):

> **Steirisch:**
>   Und i wea koit und imma köta
>   I wea obgebrüht und öta
>   Owa des wüll i ned und des muas i jez klean:
>   I mecht loch, taunzn, singan und **rean**
>   Ångst und Schmeazn sulln mi wida wiagn
>   Und die Liebe mecht i bis in die Zechnspitzn spian

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kFGnsn_om8 Refrain ab 1:08

> **Standarddeutsch:**
>   Und ich werde kalt und immer kälter
>   Ich werde abgebrüht und älter
>   Aber das will ich nicht, und das muss ich jetzt klären:
>   Ich möchte lachen, tanzen, singen und **weinen**
>   Angst und Schmerzen sollen mich wieder würgen (quälen)
>   Und die Liebe möchte ich bis in die Zehenspitzen spüren.

Die Bedeutung von *rean* ist mir vollkommen klar; tatsächlich kannte ich *rean* lange vor *weinen* (wie gesagt: Ost-Steirisch ist meine eigentliche Muttersprache, Standarddeutsch habe ich erst in der Schule gelernt). Aber nachdem ich dem Wort keine offenkundige Nähe zu irgend einem anderen deutschen Wort ansehe, frage ich mich, wie es kommt, dass zwei so verschiedene Wörter wie *rean* und *weinen* dasselbe bedeuten können, wo *rean* eigentlich herkommt, und ob es immer schon die Bedeutung von *weinen* hatte.

<sub>*Der im Osten der Steiermark gesprochene Dialekt ist ein südmittelbairischer Dialekt, gehört also zu den mittelbairischen Dialekten, die auch in Nieder- und Oberbayern gesprochen werden. Nach einer anderen Systematik, die den Begriff "donaubairisch" für jene Dialekte verwendt, die rund um München, Salzburg, Passau, Linz, St. Pölten und Wien gesprochen werden, ist es ein sübbayrischer Dialekt, gehört also einer anderen Unterart der bairischen Dialekte an als das, was in Bayern gesprochen wird. Aber soweit mir bekannt ist, gibt es das Verb* »rean« *ohnehin in allen bairischen Dialekten.*</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Deutsche Wörterbuch enttäuscht wie gewohnt nicht und bietet:

> [REHREN](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=14,561,10), *verb. brüllen, blöken, schreien; ein im westgermanischen verbreitetes wort, ahd.* rêrên […] *mhd.* rêren; *ags.* rârigean, *mittelengl.* rârin, *neuengl.* roar;

Die Bedeutung *weinen* is alt. Es werden Belege aus dem Altenglischen, Niederdeutschen und Westfälischen gegeben. Zu der in der Frage genannten Region heißt es:

> *sonst, namentlich im bair. sprachgebiete mit dem nebenbegriff des kindischen oder feigen, daher tirol.* der rearer, *mensch der immer weint, schimpf gegen verzagte, mutlose.* Schöpf *a. a. o.; in Kärnten von heulenden kindern:*
>
> rearen und lachen
> geat zamm in an kachel.
>
> *kinderreim bei* Lexer 207;

Das DWB bezieht sich hier auf Schöpfs *Tirolisches Idiotikon*, wo *weinen* als erste Bedeutung genannt wird:

> **[rêren](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10584337_00571.html?zoom=1), rearen,** v, 1) laut weinen, weinen überhaupt. Der **rearer,** Mensch, der immer weint; Schimpf gegen Verzagte, Muthlose; das **grear, rearach**, das Weinen, Klagen. – Der **hoamrearer**, der immer weinend nach Hause verlangt.

Der Kinderreim stammt aus Lexer, *Kärntisches Wörterbuch*; siehe [hier](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10523325_00126.html?zoom=1).

Das Schweizerische *Idiotikon* kennt das Verb als [rärre<sup>n</sup>](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id6.htm#!page/61223/mode/1up); die Bedeutung *weinen* unter 2. a).

Die neuhochdeutsche Form *röhren* (vom DWB als *Nebenform* zu *rehren* bezeichnet) steht dagegen ausschließlich für das Schreien der Tiere.

Comment: Das wird wohl eine Schreibvariante von *röhren* sein? (Was der Hirsch tut.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *Rehren* ist die altehrwürdige Form, *röhren* die neue. DWB bezeichnet sie als *Nebenform*.

Comment: vgl. *röcheln* (s. retroflexes allophone zu /x/ bzw. /r/), bei DWDS darunter auch *raunen*, sowie nicht nachvollziehbar *Rost* (Gitter). Man denke an En. *rooster* (Braten, oder Krähe? haha, ein Wortspiel). Dort ist auch ein echtes Homonym aus Fränkisch \*hrata ("Bienenwabe"; vgl. *crate*? *Raute*, das ist Oberdeutsch bzw. Latein *Rhombus*?) gelistet, vgl. deshalb *krähen, krächzen, krakelen, Krach, rauschen*, etc. etc. Pfeifer nennt diese lautmalerisch. Was aber ist mit *reor*, *oreo* (u.ä.?)? Wohl nicht hier *reiern* "speien, kotzen" wie der Vogel *Reier*, aber wer weiß.

Comment: Aber s. dahingehend *rotz*. zu *crate* vgl. *Ranzen* (Tornister, Schul-Mappe) hinsichtlich *ranzen, anranzen, rounzen* wohl bei *raunen*. In diesem Sinne (Gefäß) vgl. *Rachen, Kehle* (eher Öffnung, Hals). Lautlich nahe *rage, Rache*, so auch *rasen*. Bzgl. *weinen* s. insb. *Träne*, En. *tear* (lt. wiki von "zerren, reißen"); *reißen* wiederum aus  zusammenfall von Germ. \*hritana und \*writana, beide "scratch" daher auch Nl. *wri...* "quarrel", En *write*, sowie *Reißbrett*. Und da passt es, dass Pfeifer *Rune* bei *raunen* vermutet. *rufen* aus UrG \*ker (Pokorny) legt *hr* in *re-hr-en* nah

Comment: während *re-* woanders vermutet werden könnte (wobei Pfeifer nach Pokorny einen Stamm \*re- \*reu vermutet). Deshalb auch *ch* aus *k* in *röcheln*. Alles geraten, da blickt doch keiner duach. Vgl. übrigens auch [to rear](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rear) (s.  dort ety 2).